# How to check if cURL logged in succesfully? c++

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

so I am trying to make a c++ script that will log in into a website and output the source code into the dump.txt.
Is there a way to find out if the script logged in succesfully?

code:

```
#include "pch.h"
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <curl/easy.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    FILE* logfile;

    logfile = fopen("dump.txt" , "wb");

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "");`enter code here`
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_STDERR, logfile);

        // Visit the login page once to obtain a PHPSESSID cookie
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://forum.nephrite.ro/index.php?app=core&module=global&section=login/");
        curl_easy_perform(curl);


        // Now, can actually login. First we forge the HTTP referer field, or HTS will deny the login
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://forum.nephrite.ro/index.php?app=core&module=global&section=login/");
        // Next we tell LibCurl what HTTP POST data to submit
        char data[] = "ips_username=xxx&ips_password=xxx";
        char *ptrToString = data;
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data);
        curl_easy_perform(curl);

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

        fclose(logfile);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are sibmitting an HTML webform for login instead of using HTTP authentication, so the only way to validate the login is successful is to look at the content of the response HTML and see if it is what you are expecting. Or, if the server uses URL redirects, check if the final URL is not an error page or the login page again. You typically can't detect webform success/failure at the HTTP layer alone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html) & [CURLOPT_WRITEDATA](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEDATA.html) to capture the page that curl fetched, and check if it contains a "login successful" string, something like

```
size_t curl_write_callback(const void * read_ptr, const size_t size,
        const size_t count, void *s_ptr)
{
    (*(string*) s_ptr).append((const char*) read_ptr, size * count);
    return count;
}
```

and then

```
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://forum.nephrite.ro/index.php?app=core&module=global&section=login/");
    string html;
    curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_WRITEDATA,&html);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION,curl_write_callback);
    curl_easy_perform(curl);
    if(html.find_first_of("Welcome back Dave!")!=string::npos){
          // login successful!
    } else{
         // login failed
    }
```

just replace `Welcome back Dave!` with some string that is only presented to you when the login is successful.  and by the way, when using c++, don't use a lambda for CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, and if you're gonna use a class member for the callback, the class member function *must* be static, otherwise you're likely to get runtime crashes.. (been there, done that >.< )